# Get the content from the output APK of aapt2 link

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle, aapt2, bundletool

I'm trying to create Android App Bundle (.aab) as it is described here [Build your app from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline).

I first compile the resources:

```
aapt2 compile res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png -o compiled_resources 
aapt2 compile res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png -o compiled_resources 
aapt2 compile res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png -o compiled_resources
aapt2 compile res/values/strings.xml -o compiled_resources
```

And then use the link command:

```
aapt2 link --proto-format -o output.apk -I android.jar --manifest manifest/AndroidManifest.xml -R compiled_resources/drawable-hdpi_icon.png.flat compiled_resources/drawable-ldpi_icon.png.flat compiled_resources/drawable-mdpi_icon.png.flat compiled_resources/values_strings.arsc.flat  --auto-add-overlay
```

Now I want to create the base.zip folder for the `bundletool`, and it requires, as it is stated in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline), the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `resources.pb` files, which are located within the output.apk file that the earlier `aapt2 link` command created.

[Compile and link your app's resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#compile_and_link_your_apps_resources) says: "You can then extract content from the output APK".

I did a search online and found some methods to extract files from an `apk`. The most popular one includes `apktool` with the simple command: `apktool d output.apk -f`, another one uses `aapt` with: `aapt d xmltree output.apk AndroidManifest.xml`.

Both of these commands fail with `xml` reading errors.

My guess is that the reason for that is that `AndroidManifest.xml` is not really an `xml` file as one would expect in a regular `apk` file (created with `aapt` for example), but an `xml` file of the `protobuf format`, which `apktool` and `aapt` don't expect.

Does anybody know how the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#compile_and_link_your_apps_resources) expect us to: "extract content from the output APK"?

Comment: apktool does not "extract" `AndroidManifest.xml` it decompiles it (plus the rest of the APK). Have you tried to simply unzip the APK file?

Comment: Thank you so much. jar xf output.apk simply did it.